# Django creating a new variable from an existing model field entry

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model-view-controller

This is a small example for what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have a charField in my model

```
name = models.charField(max_length=50)
```

What do I do if I want to create a new variable called `lowercase_name`, from the text entered in name.

Obviously `lowercase_name = name.lower()` in the model doesn't work, because it is a field and not a string *yet*.

**Would I do this in the view then? If so how?** Say there are 100 instances, so 100 different names, I also want a `lowercase_name` that corresponds with each `name`, without having to fill out a field.

I'm new to Django and trying to figure this out. It would eventually have to be passed to a template so I could access both `Person.name` and `Person.lowercase_name`

Comment: Do you really need to store this in the database? Just as simple to calculate them on display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just display your name in lowercase, you can use template tags like that in your template.html.

```
{{ name|lower }}
```